# Why do we need inner interfaces, especially with the private access modifier?

Tags: java, access-modifiers

I am new to Java. Recently I read about inner interfaces and it's very confusing to me: first why they are used, and second why they can be declared private too as opposed to outer interfaces. In my opinion interfaces should be public so that they can be used by all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Purpose of an inner interfaces in java as below

1. solving the namespacing issue when the interface has a common name
2. increasing encapsulation
3. increasing readability by grouping related interfaces in one place.

A nested interface can be declared as public, private, or protected. 
This differs from the top-level interface.The top-level interface must either be declared as public or use the default access level.

Declaration of an inner interface in the body of another interface.

```
public interface Items {
            interface MyList {
            }
        }
```

Declaration of an inner interface in the body of another class.

```
 public class Items{
                public interface MyList {
                    void add(Items items);
                    String getItesmNames();
                }
        }
```

Finally, we can Implement as per below

```
public class SpecialItems implements Items.MyList  {

}
```

When a nested interface is used outside of its enclosing scope, it must be qualified by the name of the class or interface of which it is a member.

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of inner interfaces or nested interfaces is to group similar things. Consider Map interface in collections. It has an nested interface called Entry. An entry cannot exist without a map, so logically it makes sense to group them together. On the other hand there might be other interfaces by name Entry which will cause namespace collisions. Thus nested interfaces are used.
To answer the other question, in any occasion use of access modifiers is to prevent unauthorized access. Making the nested interfaces private will prevent other developers to implement them in an undesired fashion. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: any idea why private access specifier?

Comment: @HarshChaturvedi What is confusing about the private access modifier? It says exactly what the access modifier intends: for only the encapsulating class to access it. Whether it's a good _design_ decision, that is a different question (and IMO is a candidate for being a code smell).

Comment: you can refer to below answer to get a clear idea of access modifiers in inner classes @HarshChaturvedi